# How to hide specific term/field value on the node?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, nodes

Is there a way to hide a specific taxonomy terms (specific field values) on the node? (not hiding field/vocabulary altogether, just some values).

For instance, there is vocabulary "Location" with a stucture like:

- Europe

  - England
  - - London
  - France
  - - Paris

On the **node** view I need to hide terms "Europe", "England" and "France" and display "London" and "Paris" only.

Answer (score 0):

Each term has a level. So if you want to show only the terms from level 2 (London, Paris) you could loop over your terms, check the level and hide if its not 2. If you need to have individual rules for hide / show, then you could add a field to the term where you can save a value to show or hide and use this in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I have tried in D7. I am doing it while node (Node No 1/Node No 2) is being created or, edited. So, changes will get reflected in node view as well. (There can be other approaches like using 'Hierarchical Select'). Here is the code :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_validate()
 * @param $node
 * @param $form
 * @param $form_state
 * @return unknown_type
 */

function common_operations_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  if ($node->type == 'node_no') { // If node is of type 'node_no' 
    if (isset($node->field_region_and_state[$node->language])) {
      if (count($node->field_region_and_state[$node->language]) > 1) { // Multiple terms are associated
        foreach ($node->field_region_and_state[$node->language] as $key => $val) {
          $vid = 0; $children = array(); // Variable Declaration & Initialization   
          // Helper function call to get 'VID' for a 'TID'
          $vid = common_operations_get_term_vid($val['tid']);
          // Get all children for a 'TID'
          $children = taxonomy_get_children($val['tid'], $vid);

          if (count($children)) { // Restricting user to select only last level term in the hierarchy  
            form_set_error('field_region_and_state', 'Some Message.');
          } 
        }
      }
      else { // Only a single term is associated 
        $vid = 0; $children = array(); // Variable Declaration & Initialization

        // Helper function call to get 'VID' for a 'TID'
        $vid = common_operations_get_term_vid($node->field_region_and_state[$node->language][0]['tid']);
        // Get all children for a 'TID'
        $children = taxonomy_get_children($node->field_region_and_state[$node->language][0]['tid'], $vid);

        if (count($children)) { // Restricting user to select only last level term in the hierarchy  
          form_set_error('field_region_and_state', 'Some Message.');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Helper function to get 'VID' for a 'TID'
 * @param $tid
 * @return unknown_type
 */

function common_operations_get_term_vid($tid) {
  $vid = 0; // Variable Declaration & Initialization

  $query = db_select ('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd' );
  $query->fields ('ttd', array ('vid'));
  $query->condition ('ttd.tid', $tid, '=');
  $vid = $query->execute ()->fetchField ();

  return $vid;
}
```

1) 'common_operations' is name of module

2) 'node_no' is type of node

3) Structure -

```
   Europe
     England
          London
            Node No 1
   France
     Paris
            Node No 2

Here, 'Node No 1' is a node of type 'node_no' associated with immediate parent in the hierarchy 'London'
      'Node No 2' is a node of type 'node_no' associated with immediate parent in the hierarchy 'Paris'
```

4) field_region_and_state is the 'Term Reference' field in content of type 'node_no'

So, when you try to create/edit the node you can associate the node only with the last level of the hierarchy.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If some the terms are not displayed on the site at all you want to think of it in a wider scope. One solution would be to answer  [Taxonomy Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_permissions) disallow authenticated users from viewing it.